# Spring @RequestMapping Ajax url does not match

Tags: ajax, spring, request-mapping

i'am trying to send get-request to my spring-handler, but it does not work.
My handler:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/master_record/details")
public @ResponseBody String user(@RequestParam(value="user") String user_name,
                                 @RequestParam(value="password") String password) {
    return "/success";
}
```

And my ajax-request:

```
function toggleHistory(nuser, pw){

        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : 'master_record/details',
            data : {"user":  nuser, "password": pw},
            success : function(result) {
                 console.log("SUCCESS");
            },
            error : function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {                   
                console.log("Error is ", textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });         
    };
```

When i'am looking on the link, i see:

> http://localhost:8080/webapp/master/master/record?user=me&password=secret&_=149440118200

i see third parameter and value: _=149440118200
Which parameter is that?

**ErrorLog**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /webapp/master/master_record/details. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have @Controller for your controller class?

Comment: What is do you mean by does not work?

Comment: Yes, i have @Controller for my controller class. Other routes work well.
I mean, i see this message:

GET http://localhost:8080/webapp/master/master/record?user=me&password=secret&_=1494401182000 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you show your class level `@RequestMapping`, I think that's what causes the problem !?

Answer (score 2):

well its clear that your url is wrong

```
    function toggleHistory(nuser, pw){

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : 'http://loclhoast:8080/master/record',
        data : {"user":  nuser, "password": pw},
        success : function(result) {
             console.log("SUCCESS");
        },
        error : function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {                   
            console.log("Error is ", textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });         
};
```

when you set url to "master/record" it will take the path after the path of your project which is clearly located under webapp/master.

You need to specify the full URL of the machine you are running you server on, in my example its localhost:8080 which is the default of the tomcat.

Comment: when i'm trying url like 'http://loclhoast:8080/master/record', i get error like:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I wonder because I used to be use simple url-part like url: 'newRoute' and it works fine, but not now...

Comment: This is a different error, the error is talking about the CORS protocol which denies requests from different domains, you can add CORS mapping for specific method in your application using WebMvcConfigurer

Comment: sorry, of course i mean urls which i tried like this: http://localhost:8080/master/master_record/details    and www.localhost:8080/webapp/master/master_record/details but it still not working. I can not recognize why

Comment: did you try to request these urls using http client app like postman?

Comment: nice idea. when i try it with this url: 

www.localhost:8080/webapp/master/master_record/details?user=me&password=secret&_=1494408977498

i will be redirected to the login-page. As response i see DOM-document within postman.

Comment: www.localhost:8080/webapp/master/master_record/details?user=‌​me&password=secret&_‌​=1494408977498 this link is not correct, in spring the default servlet dispatcher will point you to the root of the machine you are running on incase you deployed root and to the root+your project in case you deployed other than the root

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143864/discussion-between-roma-kap-and-amer-qarabsa).

Comment: yeah that what i said in the answer?